# FvwmCommand WindowList - get layer information

Tags: rhel, window-manager, window-management, wmctrl, fvwm

I'm trying to get information about running windows with all the information that is shown in the menu of "[FvwmCommand WindowList](http://soc.if.usp.br/manual/fvwm/html/commands/WindowList.html)" output. (Redhat Linux 7)

The problem with this command is that it shows a pop-up menu, instead of printing the output on console.

The alternative I found is [wmctrl](http://tripie.sweb.cz/utils/wmctrl/).

```
wmctrl -lG # Prints most of the information as FvwmCommand WindowList
```

However, it does not give "layer" information.

Per help page for "FvwmCommand WindowList":

> The format of the geometry part is: desk(layer): x-geometry sticky, where desk and layer are the corresponding numbers and sticky is empty or a capital S

`wmctrl -lG` gives information about desktop, but not the layer.

Is there any way, I can get layer of particular window (`windowId`)?

Answer (score 0):

The original `xwininfo` command shows the Window id, so that should be what you want.

Normally you run `xwininfo` and then you click on the window of which you want the info. You can also specify the window id (which is not much use to you), or you can specify the name of the window (which is typically the title shown in the top bar).

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't want windowId. I want the layer for given windowId.